# MySql increment field for each key value insertion and handle duplicates as well

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

**Background**

I have a table with two columns, the one is the key, which is `word` and the other is not a key, and it's `instances`.
I want to insert each word to a new row, and increment it's `instances` field by 1.
Now, if the word that being inserted now is already exist, it should not be duplicated but it's `instances` filed should be incremented.

**Example**

1. table is empty at start
2. inserting the word "hello" and increment it's `instances` by 1.
3. inserting the word "world" and increment it's `instances` by 1.
4. inserting the word "hello" again and increment it's `instances` by 1.

So now the table will look like this:

```
hello   2
world   1
```

**I have tried:**

```
MySql_Connection.query("

    INSERT INTO `my_database`.my_table 
    (`word`) VALUES ('"+ word_to_insert +"') 
    UPDATE  `instances` = `instances` + 1 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY `instances` = `instances` + 1

");
```

**getting a syntax error**

Comment: Post syntax error and what it's that language?

Comment: I think he is saying that you should add the proper error that the language is printing like `mysql-a7657-error: syntax error` or something like so. And about the language, you add only tags to the mysql problem, but you are also using a programming language here: `MySql_Connection.query(` so...

Comment: And by the way, your error is because you are mixing an insert command with an update command. Either separete than or put a semi colon `;` after the insert command, if the language supports it, it will run...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement should be

```
MySql_Connection.query("

    INSERT INTO `my_database`.my_table 
    (`word`) VALUES ('"+ word_to_insert +"') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `instances` = `instances` + 1

");
```

instead.

You should provide an DEFAULT value for your `instances` column too, to get the value of `1` in your instances column if inserting a new word.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    word VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    instances INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
);
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4c5c/1)